# Indicate whether file has uncommited changes in mode line

Tags: mode-line, git, vc

In my mode line I can see if a buffer has unsaved changes (`**-` or a red `x` in my case, since I am using [`smart-mode-line`](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line)).

Is there a similar way to display whether or not the file visited by the current buffer has uncommitted changes in  Git or whatever VCS you are using?

Comment: If you don't mind using up a column next to the buffer instead of showing it on the mode line, [Git Gutter mode](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-gutter) might work.

Comment: @ScottWeldon I love git-gutter-mode, but I have to be in an area with changes in order to see that there are changes. I would like to be able to whether or not there are changes regardless of my position in the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `vc` does that by default.  From its [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VC-Mode-Line.html#VC-Mode-Line) (emphasis mine):

> When you visit a file that is under version control, Emacs indicates
>   this on the mode line.  For example, ‘Bzr-1223’ says that Bazaar is used
>   for that file, and the current revision ID is 1223.
>
> **The character between the back-end name and the revision ID indicates
>   the "version control status" of the work file.  In a merge-based version
>   control system, a ‘-’ character indicates that the work file is
>   unmodified, and ‘:’ indicates that it has been modified**.  ‘!’ indicates
>   that the file contains conflicts as result of a recent merge operation
>   (*note Merging::), or that the file was removed from the version
>   control.  Finally, ‘?’ means that the file is under version control, but
>   is missing from the working tree.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I didn't look into this enough before asking. I guess I always looked when I already had changes in a file, and didn't want to undo all those changes to see what in my mode line changed. What you say is correct though, and with `smart-mode-line` the color of the branch name even changes! Thanks again for steering me in the right direction!

Comment: ? I only have Git:branch-name in the mode-line. Yes, I tested it in a basic Emacs.

Comment: @yPhil Isn't your file modified?  The `:` says that.